# Why does my function still provide a repeat value at times?

Tags: python

I wrote a recursive function hoping that it would return a random element in a list, not repeating itself.  Occasionally it repeats still.  Any thoughts?

```
def random_from_list_generator(list, previous_element=''):
    index = random.randrange(0, len(list))
    new_element = list[index]
    if previous_element != new_element:
      return new_element
    else:
      return random_from_list_generator(list, previous_element)
```

Comment: do you mean that the element is equal to the previous element ? or you run the loop N times and you see a value repeating after some iterations ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by: "occasionally it repeats"?

Comment: "not repeating itself" - your function only returns one item, so how could anything be repeated? If you mean that you expected successive calls to return different values, then you need to show how you use this function, as it doesn't contain any mechanism to prevent that in itself

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed Yes, I run the loop N times and see the value repeat on some iterations. (comparing previous element from the same list as the new element from that list)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille - I meant to say the return value repeats occasionally.  If the list was fruits, it would go something like this:    apple, pear, grape, apple, apple, plum, orange, grapefruit, orange, orange, apple.               (It's the apple, apple or orange, orange behavior not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you call the function. Consider:

```
import random


def random_from_list_generator(list, previous_element=''):
    index = random.randrange(0, len(list))
    new_element = list[index]
    if previous_element != new_element:
        return new_element
    else:
        return random_from_list_generator(list, previous_element)

# coould have a run sequence
results = []
for i in range(10):
    results.append(random_from_list_generator([1,2,3,4]))

print(results) #  [4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2] 

# does not have a run sequence
results = []
for i in range(10):
    prev = results[-1] if i != 0 else ''
    results.append(random_from_list_generator([1,2,3,4], prev))

print(results) #  [4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3]
```

The two different calls have different behavior. The first can have a 'run' the second will not.

As an aside, it would be better to not use reserved words (`list`) for arguments, this is used to construct lists from other structures. For example, (purely artificial)

```
list({1,2,3})
```

creates a list from a set.

Comment: Thanks...the reserved word thing as well...I should know that.  Appreciated

Comment: @RickRieger Happy to help. If this is something where execution time matters you could remove the overhead of recursive calls with a while loop.

Comment: You know what's funny, I'm almost certain the way I'm implementing the recursive call IS in-fact like your second example.  On the first call, the second param is an empty string.  Second and consecutive calls after the previous value is passed to second param.  I still get a repeat value on occasion.  argh

Comment: @RickRieger if you're referring to the code you posted that defines `random_from_list_generator()`, the  `previous_element` is ***not*** overwritten. The same value is passed each time.

Comment: (small lightbulb in cloud above head) I'm new at python I thought it would override...again thanks

Comment: @RickRieger if this answers your question in full consider marking the answer correct (to display a green checkmark) this ensures we keep correct records on Stack Overflow.